# Laravel 4.2 filter access to uploaded files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to route to filter access to files in upploads folder.

```
Route::get('uploads/{class}/{id}/{filename}', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    return "route works";
}));
```

the code above works for link `uploads/Deviation/1/Laravel%20Cheatsheet`, but if the link is to an actual file `uploads/Deviation/1/Laravel%20Cheatsheet.pdf`, it seems like laravel is bypassing router. I get why does it do it, but is there a way to bend the rules for uploads folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended Laravel Apache configuration is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The recommended nginx configuration is:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Both of these prioritize any files with that exact filename first, falling back to Laravel's index.php **only** if a file is not found. This is fairly important - you don't want the largeish PHP framework involved in serving static files like CSS/JS/images, it'd be a heavy load on the server.

If you want to sit Laravel in front of your uploads, just use a different URL to reference them, and have Laravel serve the file after you've done whatever it is you need to do.

```
Route::get('not-the-real-uploads/{class}/{id}/{filename}', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    // something like this
    return Response::download('uploads/...', ...);
}));
```

Comment: This is what I did. I created .htaccess file to `deny from all` for uploads folder and `return Response::download...` from `show($id)` method in `AttachmentsController`

Answer (score 2):

By default characters like slashes and dots are not allowed in parameter values. In order to override that, you'll need to define the route as follows:

```
Route::get('uploads/{class}/{id}/{filename}', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
  return "route works";
}))->where('filename', '[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+');
```

Just make sure that you don't store the files in publicly accessible location - I suggest to store it somewhere in **storage/**.

Comment: This won't really address the more fundamental issue - if a real file exists at that URL, Laravel won't be involved at all in the request. The webserver will just serve the file directly.

Comment: It is  true for all routes you define in laravel, not only this one, so it's a matter of properly redirecting all necessary routes to Laravel